# Directive Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have three html screens.

Screen1.html:

```
<button id="screenbtn"></button>
```

Screen2.html:

```
<div id="sctmpl">
  <label>Label for screen two</label>
</div>
```

Screen3.html:

```
<div id="sctmpl1">
      <label>Label for screen three</label>
    </div>
```

All these screens are in different folders but under same root.

So on click of the button I need to toggle between screen2 and screen3, need to achieve using Angular Js.

As it is easy to manipulate in Jquery which I already achieved, but the scenario is to achieve in Angular JS.

Can any one please let me know how to achieve this with basic demo.

Comment: Are you having problems with some particular Angular code? This is pretty comprehensively covered in most tutorials & the documentation

Comment: Better read the documentation before using a framework. This is typically described in the official AngularJS tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Try using redirectTo command in templateURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a routeprovider.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
  return $routeProvider.when('/screen1', {
    templateUrl: 'screen1.html',
    controller: 'aController'
  }).when('/screen2', {
    templateUrl: 'screen2.html',
    controller: 'bController'
  });
});

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-href="#screen1">Screen 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#screen2">Screen 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

I made a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uEH8THJ907BuUtboSy9K?p=preview)

Keep in mind that in order to use the ngRoute you need to include it in your project.